# How to set the background of particular component in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I want to change the background color of specific (login) component in my app, but it's working. Here is my html page

```css
.bg {
  background: #1f4037;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #99f2c8, #1f4037);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #99f2c8, #1f4037);
}
```

```html
<div class='bg'>
  <div style="margin-top: 60px;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6 mx-auto'>
          <div class='card'>

            <div class='card-header'>
              <div>
                <h4 class='text-center'>Login</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='card-body'>
              <form class='form'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label>Email:</label>
                  <input class='form-control' name='email' [(ngModel)]='user.username' type='email'>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input class='form-control' name='password' [(ngModel)]='user.password' type='password'>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type='button' class='btn btn-success float-right' (click)='loginUser()'>Login</button>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class='text-center'>
                    <a routerLink='/register'>Don't have account ? Sign Up</a><br />
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' routerLink='/register'>Register</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

although the above code works, but it only sets to half of page not the complete page, I've tried changing the height to 100% but it doesn't worked either

Comment: in what file have you defined this `. bg` class?

Comment: can you put your demo code here fork and post link that we can see it in angular version :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Comment: Is your login component the only one in the screen? can you post a codepen or such ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your container height with `100vh`.

> **[vh](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/)** - This unit is based on the height of the viewport. A value of 1vh is equal to 1% of the viewport height.

By doing so this will fit your content according to the viewport Height of your webpage.

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ru6ebc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: my content is not so exceeding the complete page, but why do there is a scroll bar ?

Comment: you can put your requirement there too like `overflow: hidden` as per your requirement,

Comment: @Lint also because you have set `margin-top` remove that which leads to scroll bar

Answer (score 1):

Change the height to 100vh

```
.bg {
  background: #1f4037;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #99f2c8, #1f4037);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #99f2c8, #1f4037);
  height : 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The

```html
<div class='bg'>
```

will get the height of it's own inner elements.

You might need to add some paddings for the `bg` class:

```css
.bg {
  background: #1f4037;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #99f2c8, #1f4037);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #99f2c8, #1f4037);
  padding: 50px
}
```

Comment: I also needed to set `height :100vh` it was not working with this